# Getting started with Kinect + OpenNI + Qt on Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, kinect, openni

I would like to write a simple application using Kinect, OpenNI and Qt on Windows 7.
I have installed OpenNI, NITE, the SensorKinect driver, Qt Creator and Visual Studio 2010. Now, is there a tutorial, guide, or a simple base application where I could start from?

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure if you want to use C++, C# or VB, I'll try to give the places that helped me get started. I use C#.

To know the concepts and how it works, I suggest reading this: http://openni.org/Documentation/ProgrammerGuide.html

For an easier start, you could use Nui.Vision from Vangos Pterneas, read this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169161/Kinect-and-WPF-Complete-body-tracking.aspx

There are some WinForms samples for .NET, check the tutorials on OpenNI.org (the C# .NET ones).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use the Microsoft Drivers at http://kinectforwindows.org

There are several video tutorials that are very good that go along with these binaries found here:
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/

This is where I would start for beginners:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/resources/

This being said, you can't use OpenNI and Kinect For Windows.  Only one or the other.

Comment: I've chosen OpenNI over MS Kinect SDK for two reasons: 1) Licensing 2) OpenNI supports a wider array of devices.

Comment: I understand the second reason, but as for licensing, if you get one of the Kinect for Windows Kinects, the licensing cost is in the device.  IE, you can develop whatever you want on it. Either way, good luck with your application!  NUI is a very exciting space to be in :)